# Trying to get resized image from app engine through appending "=sxx" to URL

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, resize, blobstore

I'm trying to get resized image from app engine through appending "=sxx" to URL as described in [the image app engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview). I'm doing this from the Android client.

After getting the blob key for my image I have this URL:

```
https://myapp.appspot.com/mobile/serve_image?blob-key=1233xblabla
```

This all works, however once I tell the app engine to give me that picture with 70 pixels at the longest side by appending "=s70", the BitmapFactory tells me, the URL is not valid. So the URL I do this with is (is this how it is supposed to work?):

```
https://myapp.appspot.com/mobile/serve_image?blob-key=1233xblabla=s70
```

The code I'm using is this:

> URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL + "/serve_image?blob-key=" + photo + "=s70");                                            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()                                                    .getInputStream());

Answer (score 3):

You don use use a get serving url. A get serving url looks like this. Try it :

```
https://lh6.ggpht.com/lOghqU2JrYk8M-Aoio8WjMM6mstgZcTP0VzJk79HteVLhnwZy0kqbgVGQZYP8YsoqVNzsu0EBysX16qMJe7H2BsOAr4j=s70
```

HTML :

```
<img  alt="image" src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/lOghqU2JrYk8M-Aoio8WjMM6mstgZcTP0VzJk79HteVLhnwZy0kqbgVGQZYP8YsoqVNzsu0EBysX16qMJe7H2BsOAr4j=s70"/></a>
```

Comment: yup you need to call getServingUrl first, and then be using that URL for your images.

Comment: But I canät do that just from the client can I?

Comment: You can do it, by putting the result of of the getServingUrl in your template.

Comment: Sorry, from wwhat do I have to call getServingURL()? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Here is an example from Google in Java : http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/